# How can I use a while loop to execute this code properly in UNIX?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

```
echo -n "Enter a positive integer: "; read integer
  While [ $integer -gt 0 ]; do
    echo "$integer"
  done
```

I am trying to write a script in UNIX that meets the following criteria:

1. Name the script `while.sh`.
2. Ask the user to enter a positive integer.  You can assume that the user will enter a positive integer (input validation not required).
3. Use a while loop to print all integers from 0 up to and including the integer entered.

The first two steps were easy, but I cannot get the third step to execute properly. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Use `expr` to increment a variable: `x=\`expr $x + 1\``

Comment: You need a "counter" variable that starts at 0 and stops when greater than the user's value.

Comment: I did not know the expr command, that will be useful in the future, thanks for your input.

Comment: Don't use `expr` for integer arithmetic; use the POSIX arithmetic expression; `x=$((x + 1))`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the script you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter a positive integer: "; read integer
while [ $integer -gt 0 ]; do
    echo "$integer"
    integer=`expr $integer - 1`
done
```

This is an example:

```
./while.sh 
Enter a positive integer: 10
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: or simply `((--integer))`

Comment: `((--integer))` is not a standard shell command; only some shells will support it. Instead, use `integer=$((integer - 1))` or even `: $((--integer))`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the script I came up with. I may have taken this a little to literal, however your question does ask for displaying 0 to the number entered.

```
#! /bin/bash

i=0

echo -n "Enter a positive integer: "
read integer

while [ $integer -ge $i ]
 do
  echo "$i"
  ((i++))
done
```

Here is the output from above:

```
Enter a positive integer: 11
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

Comment: That is another way to think about it. I like your way because it goes in ascending order, rather than descending.